# Installing Ubuntu OpenStack AutoPilot on VMware Workstation - network config

Tags: openstack-autopilot, vmware-workstation, subnet

I am following the instructions here:
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-autopilot-testdrive

At step 2 (!) it says "make at least a full /24 subnet available", but there are no instructions on how to do that.  Google doesn't return anything useful here either.

I have always found networking on VMware Workstation (on a Windows 8.1 laptop) to be a big mystery.  I have basic NAT & bridged networks going well on Windows and Ubuntu VMs but I don't understand how to create a subnet and use it for these Autopilot images.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the same and similarly struggled as I am also not a network person.  But here is what I did.  I have an ESXi Server..and created the network as follows:[VMware Network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybJRZ.png)  See the VMware network pic.

1. I implemented a router.  There is a fresco-043.ova that I downloaded and installed.  Make sure to disable DHCP on the router.  Note network attachments in the pic.
2. In addition to the default "VM Network" I created "VM Network2" with no vmnic attached (therefore an internal network).
3. Ignore the VM Network-Internal it is not used for this example.
4. When configuring your MAAS be sure to use the MAAS IP as your DNS when running the autopilot-config script.

This seemed to all work - nodes got commissioned and ready. But I I did get stuck in landscape so I am not yet sure my configuration is 100% correct.

Hope this helps.